# Konva text getting overflow outside the lable

Tags: javascript, node.js, konvajs, konva

We have integrated Konva in our project and we are facing issue with Label and Text. Text getting overflow outside the Label.
Expected behaviour
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1NRC.png)

Current Behavior:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x3BA.png)

```js
var label = new Konva.Label({
  "id": "assetLabel_62c280d6f82f05238c2a8779",
  "x": 329.3701840204836,
  "y": 78.69399520035239,
  "width": 50,
  "height": 200,
  "draggable": true
});

// It plays the role of background for role. If anything regarding to appearance of the
// label should be changed than Konva.Tag will be place to change.
var tag = new Konva.Tag({
  "fill": "#FFFF60",
  "stroke": "black",
  "strokeWidth": 0.8,
  "cornerRadius": 4,
  "shadowBlur": 6,
  "shadowColor": "blue",
  "shadowOpacity": 0.7
});

// Text displayed on the label.
var text = new Konva.Text({
  "padding": 5,
  "fill": "black",
  "align": "left",
  "fontFamily": "Open Sans",
  "fontSize": "16",
  "text": "M:1 | C:0 | T:1\nDeviceType: Mono SFP",
  "width": "auto",
  "height": "auto"
});

//clubbing labels together @important to club them together before using the label
// to avoid issues regarding to dimension.
label.add(tag).add(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@8/konva.min.js"></script>
```

We have integrated Konva in our project and we are facing issue with Label and Text. Text getting overflow outside the Label.
Expected behaviour
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1NRC.png)

Current Behavior:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x3BA.png)

Please find the code snippet :

```js
 self.label = new Konva.Label({
        id: ASSET_LABEL + assetData.properties._id,
        x: assetData.properties.labelCoordinates.x,
        y: assetData.properties.labelCoordinates.y,
        draggable: true
      });
      
       self.tag = new Konva.Tag({
        fill: config.color || Color.DARK_YELLOW,
        stroke: Color.BLACK,
        strokeWidth: LABEL_STROKE_WIDTH,
        cornerRadius: CORNER_RADIUS,
        shadowBlur: SHADOW_BLUR,
        shadowColor: Color.BLUE,
        shadowOpacity: SHADOW_OPACITY
      });
      
      self.text = new Konva.Text({
        padding: 5,
        fill: Color.BLACK,
        align: DEFAULT_TEXT_ALIGNMENT,
        fontFamily: config.fontFamily || DEFAULT_FONT_FAMILY,
        fontSize: config.fontSize || DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE,
        text: displayText
      });
      
       self.label.add(self.tag).add(self.text);
```

Comment: It looks like a Konva bug. Please create a small online demo.

Comment: As it's web application where I have added above piece of code. I am not able to create online demo

Comment: Could it be that because the width is not set then the text is not being restricted in its width ?

Comment: Might be the case, but as Text is getting render dynamically and if we set the default width and if text size/width is small then it leaves the extra spaces at the end.

Comment: Yep but this is how konva.Text.width=auto works - if you do not set a width then it will not wrap, so text will overflow as you are seeing. Try setting a numeric value for the text width, use max value you want the tag width to be.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for all your suggestions.
I got the issue and it is with fontFamily. so fontFamily is getting loaded after the Label, that was creating issue. So once fontFamily got changed, it exceeds the width.
With some fontFamily it's working fine.

I will close the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure that your fontFamily solution will work in all cases.